# Stop fixed div from scroll in a certain point. What is missing in my code? Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, scroll, fixed

I have this div called "floating" and it has to start in the bottom of the screen, but as the user scrolls, it has to move (kindly) to the top and maintain fixed until reaches another div down below.

What I have so far is making the div stops correctly, but it's not moving to the top of the screen when the user start to scroll. What is missing here?

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <a id="floating" href="#stop"></a>
  <div id="dummy">some content</div>
  <div id="stop">other content near the footer</div>
  <footer>footer</footer>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#floating{
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 5%;
  right: 5%;
  width: 115px;
  height: 115px;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #0055db;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
function checkOffset() {
  var a=$(document).scrollTop()+window.innerHeight;
  var b=$('#stop').offset().top;
  if (a<b) {
    $('#floating').css('bottom', '5%');
  } else {
    $('#floating').css('bottom', (20+(a-b))+'px');
  }
}
$(document).ready(checkOffset);
$(document).scroll(checkOffset);
```

I appreciate all the help! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
Try using JQuery Animate

 <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $(document).scroll(function(){
          $("#floating").animate({top: '10px'}, "slow");
    });
  });
 </script>
```

Comment: Hello @Robert! Thank you for your help! I got the div moving to the top, but I can't make it stop when reaches the #stop div.. I tried something like it: 


    function checkOffset() {
        var a=$(document).scrollTop()+window.innerHeight;
        var b=$('#stop').offset().top;
        if (a<b) {
            $(document).scroll(function(){
                $("#floating").animate({top: '10px'}, "slow");
            });
        } else {
            $('#floating').css('bottom', (20+(a-b))+'px');
        }
    }